# Evaluating a limit without using L'hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the value of $\alpha$ for which following limit exists and is equal to a non-zero constant
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{e \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n -1}{n^\alpha}$$

I don't know how to begin.
I don't want a full solution, I would like only a hint on how to begin.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint - 1: $e\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-1=e\cdot e^{n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}-1=e^{n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+1}-1 \ \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}-\left\{0\right\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$e\left(1-\frac {1}{n}\right)^n=e^{n\left(\ln(1-\frac {1}{n})+\frac {1}{n}\right)} $$

$$\ln\left(1-\frac {1}{n}\right)=-\frac {1}{n}-\frac {1}{2n^2}(1+\epsilon (n) )$$

thus, we will compute

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac {-(1+\epsilon (n))}{2n^{1+\alpha}}$$

You should take $$\alpha=-1$$

the limit is then $=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is not an hint but a solution in my eyes. Anyway, review your latex and results.The limit is $-\frac{1}{2}$ for $\alpha=-1$ ;)

Comment: @Ixion Thnx for the positive remark. What about Latex.

Comment: minor typos like parenthesis and an $n\to+\infty$ missed (maybe you wanted to miss it out on purpose)

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: Please note that the OP asked only for a hint. You should pay attention to such things. Some people here do not want their problems done completely for them.

Comment: @TedShifrin Have you seen the hint below.

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial theorem, $$e\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n-1=e\left(1-1+\frac{n(n-1)}2\frac1{n^2}-\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\frac1{n^3}+\cdots\right)-1\\
=e\left(1-1+\frac12\left(1-\frac1n\right)-\frac1{3!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)+\cdots\right)-1.$$

The constant terms yield

$$e\left(1-1+\frac12-\frac1{3!}+\cdots\right)-1=e\frac1e-1=0.$$

The remaining terms are

$$e\left(\frac12\left(-\frac1n\right)-\frac1{3!}\left(\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)-1\right)+\cdots\right).$$

The coefficient of $1/n$ will be $e$ times

$$\frac12(-1)-\frac1{3!}(-1-2)+\frac1{4!}(-1-2-3)-\frac1{5!}(-1-2-3-4)+\cdots,$$ which is convergent.

More precisely,

$$-\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{(k-1)k}2=-\frac12\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k-2)!}=-\frac1{2e}$$ so that the limit with $\alpha=-1$ is $-\dfrac12$.

Comment: Interesting! +1

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{e \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n -1}{n^\alpha}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{e \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n -1}{\ln\left(1+e \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n -1\right)}\cdot\frac{1+n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n^\alpha}\right)=$$
$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1+n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n^\alpha}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
for $\alpha=-1$ because $1+n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=1+n\left(-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You have to find an *equivalent* of the numerator. First find the beginning of Taylor's  expansion of the log of first term:
\begin{align}
\log\biggl(\mathrm e\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^n\biggr)&=1+n\log\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)\\&=1+n\Bigl(-\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)\Bigr)= -\frac1{2n}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n}\Bigr),
\end{align}
so
$$\mathrm e\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)^n-1=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac1{2n}+o\bigl(\tfrac1{n}\bigr)}-1=1-\frac1{2n}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n}\Bigr)-1\sim_\infty-\frac1{2n}$$
and the given expression  is asymptotically equivalent to
$$\frac{-\frac1{2n}}{n^\alpha}=-\frac1{2n^{\alpha+1}}.$$